# PHP Read Directory name in Greek?

Tags: php, encoding

I create photo Album in PHP i have my Gallery in Directory Gallery and i write code to show All Folders in that Directory.

```
$base   = "uploads/pages/Gallery";
    $thumbs = "thumbs"; 
    $get_album  = $_GET['album'];
    $openthumbs = opendir($base."/".$thumbs);

    if(!$get_album){
        echo "<center><b><p>Επιλέξτε Album</p></b></center>";
        $handle = opendir($base);

        while(($file = readdir($handle))!==FALSE){
            $file = htmlspecialchars($file);
            if(is_dir($base."/".$file) && $file !="." && $file !=".." && $file !="$thumbs"){

    ?>
    <div class="album">
    <div class="albumbody">

    </div>
    <div class="albumtitle"><?php echo "<a href='$page?album=$file'>$file</a>";?>

    </div>
    </div>
```

The Albums i can see but i have problem with the greek encoding, when i write the the name of Album in English i dont have any problem, but in greek i can't read it. All the page is in greek i don't have any problem, i have a problem only with the folder names.Can someone help me with this. Thank's very much.

Comment: Is PHP running on Windows? If so, the behavior of `readdir` is affected by the system's ANSI code page and there is nothing you can do about that (apart from changing that setting on the server of course). It may simply not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try (assuming you have the utf-8 encoding meta tag in your webpage):

```
$utf8String = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'GREEK');
```

also make sure your php file is encoded as UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: my friend i can't understand what i must to do :(

Comment: remove this $file = htmlspecialchars($file); I think it's not needed while looping through files just escape the characters whne you generate the links.Also use this tag in your pages: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> and use utf-8

Comment: also most editros - ide have options on how to save your php file (which encoding) make sure you are saving yoru files as utf-8 without BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your php file is encoded in UTF8. Check your editor for this property

Comment: i have my encoding iso-8859-7 for greek letters, and everything show fine, i cant read only the directory name, when it is in greek